# chemfig: \setchemfig error

Tags: chemfig

From [chemfig documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf), page 8.
It seems like `\setchemfig` is not defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=50pt}
    \chemfig{A-B}
\end{document}

 ! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \setchemfig {atom sep=50pt} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was
never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and
the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and
I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Client: Texmaker 4.5
Compiler: XeLaTeX

Comment: I don't get any error with the code.

Comment: As stated in the documentation, `\setchemfig` was introdued with version 1.3. You will recieve the above described error if you try to use this command with an older version of the `chemfig` package.

Comment: Well: how can I update my chemfig package?

Comment: Information on how to update your tex distribution can be found here: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/134144)

Comment: Check your distribution (MiKTeX or TeXLive for example). They have pretty *straight forward* update mechanisms.

Comment: If you definitely have to stick to an older version of `chemfig`, you can also use the matching command `\setatomsep{50pt}` that is obsolete with newer versions.